# Why is Win Server 2012 slow to read data with RAID 5?

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, raid5

We have new HP 350p server with 4x 900GB 10k SAS disks with RAID 5 (win server 2012). But disks performance to read data is to slow - it's to slow to read big directory structure on disk. Where can be a problem? 7-years old server (with old disks with RAID 1) with win server 2003 is faster to read data!

I attach the test results for both servers:

[For new server there](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5f8q0kocxcpc4c/WinServer2012Raid5.jpg?n=3994626)

[For old server there](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ae4bnz8xqjfq1f/WinServer2003.JPG?n=3994626)

Comment: Ehh, what? The Win2003 screenshot is consistently below 100 MB/s, but the 2012 exceeds 500 MB/s in almost every test.

Comment: Yes, but not for small transfer size to 4kb... Ok, but the same real test to load directory structure from disk is still faster on Win2003 (test for reading 4.38GB = 17 524 files in 3000 directories), why?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this ranging from network configured incorrectly to the source being the issue.  However assuming that the data is located locally or on a fast server I would look at the following items.  I have just built a new Dell server this week and this really helped (assuming HP has the same options)

1) DO NOT enable RTID - performance is hit hard if enabled
2) DO enable x2apic
3) DO enable I/O AT DMA
4) DO enable SR-IOV
5) DO NOT enable NMI button
6) Look at the raid set up and check that the element size is set to at least 256kb.  the larger it is the faster the process but the more space is taken up by smaller files, ie a stripe size of 1mb will use 1mb of space for a 2k file.  Larger stripes are recommended for databases however smaller strip sets impact performance.

If all this fails to improve performance then its not the setup of the RAID array causing your issue.

Good Luck
John